# How to capture the value of form submit and use it in new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am submitting a country from the drop down by the code below :-

```
<%=select_tag(:main, options_for_select(eval(forum.continent)), :prompt => "Select Country", :onchange => 'this.form.submit();')%>
```

I want to use the value which is captured here in a new form how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you should get form and submit it like this:

```
<%=select_tag(:main, options_for_select(eval(forum.continent)), :prompt => "Select Country", :onchange => '$(this).closest("form").submit();')%>
```

Comment: Anyway it is sheet code, I offer to you add class or id for select tag and write your js apart from view. Then view will be more clear and js too. Js will be like this: `$('#select_id').live('click', function() {$(this).closest('form').submit();})`

Comment: I want the country which is selected through this code should come in the new form

Comment: What do you mean 'come to form'? This parameter (it name is 'main') will post with form to the server when you submit form

Comment: If you want to send ONLY one this parameter you can send it by $.post('<url_for_create_action>', {params here}, function(data) {result here comes from server})